# Call to LocalPrintServer's GetPrintQueues hangs

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, freeze

In order to get a list of the available printers, I am using the following code:

```
new LocalPrintServer().GetPrintQueues(new[] { 
    EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Local, 
    EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Connections });
```

In the past this code worked fine, but now it hangs on the GetPrintQueues call.

What might cause this?

Comment: I'm not sure all that you get with this call but under System.Drawing.Printing you can use `PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters` to get back a StringCollection of installed printer names. It seems very fast.

Comment: Yeah I eventually switched to that. When you use `GetPrintQueues` with `EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Connections`, and any of the network servers are unreachable, it takes a long time to return. Not sure if that was the problem I was having here though.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the issue was seems to have resolved itself, so perhaps there was some problem with the print spooler that worked itself out.

I also found that, since I only need the printer names, this is slightly faster:

```
new LocalPrintServer().GetPrintQueues(
   new[] { PrintQueueIndexedProperty.Name, 
       PrintQueueIndexedProperty.Location, PrintQueueIndexedProperty.ShareName },
   new[] { EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Local, 
       EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Connections });
```